# jQuery - Get length and trigger click in increments based on length

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if I'm completely missing with the title, I'm not entirely sure how to word what it is I'm trying to achieve.  Any help would be great!!

Over the past few months in my free time I've been setting myself tasks to help myself understand and learn javascript / jQuery.  So far all is going well but I've hit a bit of a bump in the road!

Essentially what I've created is a pretty simple set of tabbed content with a changing banner.  When you click a tab, the relevant banner fades in and the previous banner fades out

**Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unn9s4yf/**

So what I'd like to do and where I'm kind of stuck is I'd like the banners to automatically "rotate", by fading in and out in the tabbed order every 10 seconds or so.

So kind of like a trigger click, but I feel as if that'd be the wrong way to go?

```
$('.thumb' + idAttr).trigger("click");
```

With a timeout attached?  I'm not sure?  I'm also not sure how to increment it each time so if this was the chosen method, how would it start at thumb 1, then click 2, 3, 4 & so on?

I've got the number of thumbs inside the div using

```
var thumbCount = $('#thumbs a').length;
```

Which returns 15 which is correct.  So I guess it'd be something like when idAttr = .length start over from 1 again?

I'd also like to be able to pause the "auto click" function when I hover overthe main banner or thumbnails, I don't know if this is achievable though?

I know I'm asking a lot here.... At least I think I am.   But any help or guidance on any part of this would be massively appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your jsfiddle and tried to do what you asked.

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/2g5Lav12/

It changes every 3 seconds, comes back to first thumb after the last thumb, stops on `mouseenter` & plays on `mouseleave` (on thumbs & banners), and stops on `click` & plays on second `click` on the same thumb.

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="thumbs">
        <a class="thumb active"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
        <a class="thumb"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <div class="banner active"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
div,
a {float: left; display: block;}

#thumbs {width: 600px;}
.thumb {width: 110px; height: 156px; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; cursor: pointer;}
.thumb:hover,
.thumb.active,
.thumb.clicked {opacity: 0.5;}

.thumb:nth-child(even) {background: #ccee44;}
.thumb:nth-child(odd) {background: #ff33dd;}

#banner {width: 360px;}
.banner {width: 360px; height: 488px; position: absolute; display: none;}
.banner.active {display: block;}

.banner:nth-child(even) {background: #ccee44;}
.banner:nth-child(odd) {background: #ff33dd;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var thumbs = $('.thumb'),
        firstThumb = thumbs.eq(0),
        banners = $('.banner'),
        all = thumbs.add(banners),
        duration = 3000,
        rotating = false,
        intervalRotate;

    function setAutoRotate(){
       intervalRotate = setInterval(autoRotate,duration);
       rotating = true;
    }

    function stopAutoRotate(){
       clearInterval(intervalRotate);
       rotating = false;
    }

    function autoRotate(){
        var nextThumb = thumbs.filter('.active').next();
        if(!nextThumb.length) nextThumb = firstThumb;
        rotate(nextThumb);
    }

    function rotate(activeThumb){
        thumbs.removeClass('active');
        activeThumb.addClass('active');
        banners.removeClass('active').eq(thumbs.index(activeThumb)).addClass('active');
    }

    thumbs.on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var thumb = $(this);
        if(thumb.hasClass('clicked')){
            thumb.removeClass('clicked');
        }else{
            stopAutoRotate();
            thumbs.removeClass('clicked');
            thumb.addClass('clicked');
            rotate(thumb);
        }
    });

    all.on('mouseenter',function(){
        if(rotating) stopAutoRotate();
    });

    all.on('mouseleave',function(){
        if(!thumbs.filter('.clicked').length) setAutoRotate();
    });

    setAutoRotate();

});
```

Is it the behaviour you wanted ?

Comment: If it doesn't work as you expected, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a click with a timeout should work fine. You could even do it recursively if you never want it to end. Also, you can set a variable to decide when to stop the rotation

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumb').click(function(event, isAutoClick){
        //Is Not automatic click, set false
        if (!isAutoClick) isRotationActive = false;

        //Other Click Code
    });

    //If hover over banner, stop rotation
    $("#banner").on("mouseover", function() {
        isRotationActive = false;
    });

    rotate($(".thumb"), 0);
});

var isRotationActive = true;

function rotate($clickables, currentIndex) {

    //Make sure currentIndex is valid
    currentIndex = currentIndex % $clickables.length;

    //Trigger current click
    $clickables.eq(currentIndex).trigger("click", [true]); //Passes [true] for isAutoClick

    //Call again in 1 second with the next index
    setTimeout(function() { 
        isRotationActive && rotate($clickables, currentIndex + 1) 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/unn9s4yf/3/

Answer (score 0):

An Additional Solution:

```
var thumbs = $('.thumb');
var currentThumb = 0;
var changingStopped = false;

var changeBanner = function() {
    console.log(thumbs.eq(currentThumb));
    thumbs.eq(currentThumb).click();
    currentThumb >= thumbCount - 1 ? currentThumb = 0 : currentThumb++;
    setTimeout(function() {
        checkIfChange();
    }, 1000);
}
// triggers 'changeBanner()' if the user isn't currently stopping it.
var checkIfChange = function() {
    if (!changingStopped)
    {
        changeBanner();
    }
}

// makes the rotation stop
$('.thumb').mouseenter(function() {
    changingStopped = true;
    $(this).trigger('click'); // Assuming you want the hovered-over thumb to be displayed in the banner.
    currentThumb = $(this).index() + 1; // Additional Option to make the rotation begin again from the current thumb.
});

// makes the rotation start again
$('.thumb').mouseleave(function() {
    changingStopped = false;
    checkIfChange();
});

checkIfChange();
```

See [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/unn9s4yf/4/). Cheers!